# Google maps - How to detect the load completion for overlay map type

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In our project we overlay a ImageMapType (google.maps.ImageMapType) over a base map using map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt method. The ImageType has getTileUrl function to fetch the tile for a particular location from the server.

I want to display a pageMask with a text message while the overlay maptype tiles are loaded and remove it once all tiles have been loaded. Is there a event to detect the load completion of these ImageMapType tiles.

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 1):

This event is fired when all visible tiles have finished loading.

`GMap2::tilesloaded()`

[Details](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.tilesloaded).